# Filldown columns from cells value in each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copying

What I am trying to do is to take values from specific cells and make them a filldown column. I have multiple worksheets with different values in them.

This code is working as expected with one worksheet :

```
Sub Formatting_one()

   Range("A12").Value = Range("M6").Value
   Range("A12:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

End Sub
```

Then, I started to try the same thing but with looping through worksheets. That's the point I am stuck with. Here is my code for this :

```
Sub Formatting_many()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.[A1].Resize(, 6).EntireColumn.Insert

        ws.Range("A12").Value = ws.Range("M6").Value
        ws.Range("A12:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("B12").Value = ws.Range("M7").Value
        ws.Range("B12:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("C12").Value = ws.Range("M8").Value
        ws.Range("C12:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("D12").Value = ws.Range("I5").Value
        ws.Range("D12:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("E12").Value = ws.Range("I4").Value
        ws.Range("E12:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("F12").Value = ws.Range("I6").Value
        ws.Range("F12:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

        ws.Range("G12").Value = ws.Range("I7").Value
        ws.Range("G12:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown

    Next ws

End Sub
```

I did a step by step, and the result is that the cell is copied in the first cell of the filldown range cells but then it's deleted. Can somebody help ?

Comment: In `Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row` you need to specify the worksheet: `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row` Also note that `7` means column G. Check if that is the correct column to look for the last used row.

Comment: Yeah, I tested that but I think Excel understands the reference between the Range() as it doesn't change anything if I put the sheet specification or not. Still have the same issue! The rows are all equal, the "7" was random, just in case I delete things while formatting my sheets :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue …

…  is that you look for the last used row in column G

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
```

But since you added 6 columns with `ws.[A1].Resize(, 6).EntireColumn.Insert` column G is now empty, so the last used row is `1`

and you actually run

```
ws.Range("A12:A1").FillDown
```

which takes the empty cell from A1 and fills it down until A12 (so your inserted value in A12 gets removed).

---

#### Solution

After inserting your original column G moved to

```
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7 + 6).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Just realized what you were explaining. Thank you very much it works now. I will specify my worksheets as well! Thank you for the advice.